# bug in package xlsxwriter: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, django, xlsxwriter

I found a bug since the version 1.1.7. I generate an excel sheet using xlsxwriter which worked fine until I upgraded to the version 1.2. 
My code:

```
def write_template_portfolio(self):
    """Create the template for portfolio
    """

    # create the worksheet
    self.current_worksheet = self.workbook.add_worksheet("Portfolio")

    # write header
    self.write_value_and_comment(1, 0, "Portfolio name", self.style_header, 'D2', 'Mandatory: The name of your Portfolio...')
    self.write_value_and_comment(1, 4, "Benchmark Name:", self.style_header, 'G2', 'Mandatory: The name of your Benchmark...')
    self.write_value_and_comment(1, 7, "Market Index Name:", self.style_header, 'J2', 'Mandatory: The name of your Market Index...')

    # qualitative information
    self.write_value_and_comment(2, 0, "Value Date", self.style_header, 'A3', 'Optional')
    self.write_value_and_comment(3, 0, "Inception Date", self.style_header, 'A4', 'Optional')
    self.write_value_and_comment(4, 0, "Manager", self.style_header, 'A5', 'Optional')
    self.write_value_and_comment(5, 0, "Philosophy", self.style_header, 'A6', 'Optional')
    self.write_value_and_comment(6, 0, "Currency", self.style_header, 'A7', 'Optional')
    self.write_value_and_comment(7, 0, "Region", self.style_header, 'A8', 'Optional')

    # time Series
    self.current_worksheet.write(5, 4, "Benchmark Value Date", self.style_header)
    self.current_worksheet.write(5, 5, "Benchmark Value", self.style_header)
    self.current_worksheet.write(5, 6, "Benchmark Type", self.style_header)
    self.current_worksheet.write(5, 7, "Market Index Value Date", self.style_header)
    self.current_worksheet.write(5, 8, "Market Index Value", self.style_header)
    self.current_worksheet.write(5, 9, "Market Index Type", self.style_header)

    for i in range(0, 25):
        self.current_worksheet.write(1, 10 + 3 * i, "Name:", self.style_header)
        self.current_worksheet.write(2, 10 + 3 * i, "Weight or Market Value:", self.style_header)
        self.current_worksheet.write(3, 10 + 3 * i, "Strategy:", self.style_header)
        self.current_worksheet.write(4, 10 + 3 * i, "Region:", self.style_header)
        self.current_worksheet.write(5, 10 + 3 * i, "Value Date", self.style_header)
        self.current_worksheet.write(5, 11 + 3 * i, "Value", self.style_header)
        self.current_worksheet.write(5, 12 + 3 * i, "Type", self.style_header)

    # change the widths
    self.current_worksheet.set_column('A:B', self.legend_width)
    self.current_worksheet.set_column('D:CG', self.value_width)
    self.current_worksheet.set_row(0, self.title_length)

    # add one lonely comment
    self.current_worksheet.write_comment('J3', 'Be consistent: put either weights for all funds or market value '
                                               'for all funds !')

    # finally, whe color one row over two in the template
    for ii in range(4, 500, 2):
        self.current_worksheet.set_row(int(ii), [], self.style_rows)

    # return the template
    self.workbook.close()

    xlsx_data = self.output.getvalue()
    return xlsx_data
```

I got the error: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'. This is a tough one. After investigation, it would appear that the problem concern the loop:

```
for ii in range(4, 500, 2):
    self.current_worksheet.set_row(int(ii), [], self.style_rows)
```

Which shows me that this bug should be related to the new version. So I tried to install different versions. I found that this bug occurs since the version 1.1.7. Are you aware of this bug? Do I have to change something in my code?[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using `set_row()` wrong (according to the [documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-set-row)). Try this instead:

```
for ii in range(4, 500, 2):
    self.current_worksheet.set_row(int(ii), None, self.style_rows)
```

Comment: Thank you Simon, I did the change but although your recommandation works for the version 1.16, I still got the same error for the other versions.

Comment: Could be, that they have made some backward incompatible changes to that function, but I cannot find any information on that.

Comment: @GillesCriton There is no known issue with `set_row()` in any version of XlsxWriter that I am aware of. If you think there is a bug then you will need to create a self-contained test case that demonstrates the issue and submit a bug report on Github. The code above cannot be run to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi jncnamara, I am going to create a self-contained test case.